# Different size buttons in vertical linear layout

Tags: android, button, layout, size

I am trying to make a vertical menu with buttons. So I have made a vertical linear layout and I am adding my buttons programmatically. The problem is that all buttons are made the same size (the size of the button with longest text). I would like to have them different size and centered. How do I do that?

My button layout:

```
    <Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/big_button"
        style="@style/button_style" >
    </Button>
```

My activity layout:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/appLogo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <ScrollView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/appLogo">

            <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/startLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

           </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Button are made programmatically:

```
    Button cityButton = (Button) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.city_button, null);
    cityButton.setText(title);
    cityButton.setId(id);
```

Button style:

```
<style name="button_style" >
    <item name="android:layout_width" >wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height" >wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor" >@drawable/button_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:gravity" >center</item>
    <item name="android:textSize" >30dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694945/set-button-height-and-width-as-wrap-content-and-fill-parent

Comment: Hey Swati, thanks! This helped me to solve the problem!

Comment: I have solved the problem by setting the width programatically:

      LayoutParams lp = cityButton.getLayoutParams();
      lp.width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
      cityButton.setLayoutParams(lp);

Comment: But I have another problem now: the padding on the sides of the button is removed now. Any idea how to fix that?